# Find the path of an application, and copy a file to that directory in Inno Setup

Tags: matlab, inno-setup

I'd like to install a file into a user's MATLAB folder in Inno Setup. But depending on the version of MATLAB, the directory can change.

In the Windows command line, it is possible to get the path of the MATLAB executable like so:

```
where matlab
```

Which will output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\matlab.exe
```

I'd like to copy a file in the following folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\toolbox\local
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` command searches the file in the path specified by the `PATH` environment variable.

In Inno Setup Pascal Script, you can implement that using [`FileSearch` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesearch), like:

```pascal
FileSearch('matlab.exe', GetEnv('PATH'))
```

*Though I'd say, that there's must be a better way to find installation folder of MATLAB.*

---

Anyway, you can resolve the path using the above method to a global variable in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup). It will also allow you to abort the installation, when MATLAB is not found.

And then you can use the variable as an installation path using a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyFile.dat"; DestDir: "{code:GetMatlabToolboxLocalPath}"

[Code]

var
  MatlabToolboxLocalPath: string;

function GetMatlabToolboxLocalPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := MatlabToolboxLocalPath;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  MatlabExePath: string;
begin
  MatlabExePath := FileSearch('matlab.exe', GetEnv('PATH'));
  if MatlabExePath = '' then
  begin
    MsgBox('Cannot find MATLAB', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  MatlabToolboxLocalPath := ExtractFilePath(MatlabExePath) + '..\toolbox\local';

  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for a perfectly working solution. I ran into a small problem, which is the case where users have multiple versions of MATLAB installed. Typing "where matlab" in the windows command line returns all paths for all versions of MATLAB installed. How can I modify the Inno Setup script to copy MyFile.dat in all MATLAB folders?

Comment: Regarding your problem: It's not a *small problem*. Ask a new question.