# Lookup all application folders and install a file there in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

This is a similar question to [Find the path of an application, and copy a file to that directory in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282559)

I'd like to install a file into a user's MATLAB folder in Inno Setup. But depending on the version of MATLAB, the directory can change, and depending on the number of versions installed, there can be multiple destinations.

In the Windows command line, it is possible to get the path of the MATLAB executable like so:

```
where matlab
```

Which will output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\matlab.exe
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\matlab.exe
```

The output of "where" shows two paths, due to the fact that two versions of MATLAB are installed. I'd like to copy a file in the following folders:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\bin
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup cannot install a file to random number of target folders on its own.

You have to code everything in Pascal Script:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyFile.dat"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure ExtractFileToPathsWhereAnotherFileIs(
  ExtractFile: string; SearchFile: string);
var
  P: Integer;
  Paths: string;
  Path: string;
  TempPath: string;
begin
  // Extract the file to temporary location (there's no other way)
  ExtractTemporaryFile(ExtractFile);
  TempPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + ExtractFile);

  Paths := GetEnv('PATH');
  // Iterate paths in PATH environment variable...
  while Paths <> '' do
  begin
    P := Pos(';', Paths);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      Path := Trim(Copy(Paths, 1, P - 1));
      Paths := Trim(Copy(Paths, P + 1, Length(Paths) - P));
    end
      else
    begin
      Path := Trim(Paths);
      Paths := '';
    end;

    // Is it the path we are interested in?
    if FileExists(AddBackslash(Path) + SearchFile) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Found "%s" in "%s"', [SearchFile, Path]));
      // Install the file there
      if FileCopy(TempPath, AddBackslash(Path) + ExtractFile, False) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Installed "%s" to "%s"', [ExtractFile, Path]));
      end
        else
      begin
        MsgBox(Format('Failed to install "%s" to "%s"', [ExtractFile, Path]),
               mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    ExtractFileToPathsWhereAnotherFileIs('MyFile.dat', 'matlab.exe');
  end;
end;
```